# Difference between "broma" and "chiste"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Both words *broma* and *chiste* translate to the English word *joke*.  What's the difference between these two Spanish words, and how do I know when to use each one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main difference that comes to my mind is that **chiste** can be something witty that you tell, like a joke. For example, the "*three guys walk into a bar...*" thing.

While **broma** is a joke that you play on someone, such as putting a sign at the wrong place.

A **broma inocente** is a joke played on someone that makes the "victim" laugh together with the ones who did the joke, something light; while a **broma pesada** is a joke that went a little too far.

If we go worse than that, then we're talking about a **burla**.

Comment: And when I just make fun of someone, and want to say "I'm just just kidding," that's a *broma*, too, right?

Comment: Yes, "estoy bromeando" or "es broma". *To pull someone's leg* is, instead, *tomar el pelo a alguien*.

Comment: Generally, a *broma* is closer to a [practical joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_joke) than a *chiste* is.

Comment: When you say "Sólo estoy bromeando" (="I'm just kidding), "bromear" is not the action of playing a prank/practical joke on someone, it usually refers  to something *you said* ironically/joking. So, I assume that "broma" could mean either "prank/practical joke" or "joke" when it means "something said in a playful or ironic way"

Comment: When you say "Sólo estoy bromeando" (= I'm just kidding), "bromear" is not the action of playing a prank/practical joke on someone, it usually refers  to something *you said* ironically/joking. So, I assume that "broma" could mean either (1) "prank/practical joke" or (2) "joke" with the meaning "something said in a playful or ironic way". On the other hand, "chiste" only means "joke", when it means "amusing and short story, usually fictional".

Answer (score 13):

- broma is like "prank" in English.

Example:

> Le hicimos una broma a Carlos.
>
> Aquellos niños le hicieron una broma pesada a Juan.

- chiste is like "to tell a joke".

Example

> El profesor nos contó un chiste que nos hizo reir.

Comment: Yes, but 'broma' is also used in a widest sense that 'prank'

Answer (score 2):

Chiste is a relatively simple concept as explained in the other answers. The thing is that broma is a complex word that has many meanings:

- Bulla, algazara, diversión.
- Chanza, burla.
- Persona o cosa pesada y molesta.

You need many words in english to explain what broma really is: to make fun of, to mock, to kid around, to have fun.

Comment: I have never heard "broma" used as "persona pesada y molesta", so I assume it must be a rare meaning. It'd be nice to mention that in your answer and give examples of each meaning.

Answer (score 2):

A "broma" can be an innocent practical joke that you pull on a person or something less innocent, but not as malicious as a "burla." In any case, it may not be funny to the other person and might cause embarrassment.

"Chiste," on the other hand refers to a joke in the sense of a humorous story, not told a someone's expense.